# Trying to make a chatbot with Express.js and Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

So, I've been trying to write this chat-app for awhile now with Node.js, express,js and socket.io and everything works well. Apart from the fact that I'm trying to include a bot called Steve. Steves purpose is to welcome you to the chat, or to have him join after you've joined and introduce himself. As well as beeing able to reply to some "commands". Hi, How are you etc. Etc.

But that part is somethin that I can't get to work.

I'm not asking of you to write the code for me. But if you could please tell me if I'm on the right track and maybe come with some ideas, tips etc. I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
users = [];
connections = [];

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
  console.log('Server running...');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  

app.get('/public', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + 'index.html')
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  connections.push(socket);
  console.log('Connected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);

  // Disconnect
  socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
    users.splice(users.indexOf(socket.username), 1);
    updateUsernames();
    connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
    console.log('Disconnected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);
  });

  // Send Message
  socket.on('send message', function(data) {

    io.sockets.emit('new message', {msg: data, user: socket.username});
  });
<code>
  // New User

  socket.on('new user', function(data, callback){
    callback(true);
    socket.username = data;
    users.push(socket.username);
    updateUsernames();
  });

  function updateUsernames() {
    io.sockets.emit('get users', users);
  }
});
```

And here's my script.js

```
$(function () {
    var socket = io.connect();
    var $messageForm = $('#messageForm');
    var $message = $('#message');
    var $chat = $('#chat');
    var $messageArea = $('#messageArea');
    var $userFormArea = $('#userFormArea');
    var $userForm = $('#userForm');
    var $users = $('#users');
    var $username = $('#username');
    var name = 'Steve', adress = 'localhost:3000', socket;


       function join(){
            socket.on('new user', name);
            socket.emit('message', "Hi! I am Steve. Steve the Chatter!");
            socket.on('new message', listener);
        };

        function listener(data){
            if(data.message=='Hi')
                socket.emit('message', 'Hi, '+$username+'.');
        };

     join();   

    $messageForm.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('send message', $message.val());
        $message.val('');
    });

    socket.on('new message', function(data) {
        $chat.append('<div class="well"><strong>'+data.user+'</strong>: '+data.msg+'</div>');
    });

    $userForm.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('new user', $username.val(), function(data) {
            if(data) {
                $userFormArea.hide();
                $messageArea.show();
            }
        });
        $username.val('');
    });

    socket.on('get users', function(data) {
        var html = '';
        for(i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
            html += '<li class="list-group-item">'+data[i]+'</li>'
                ;
        }
        $users.html(html);
    });



});
```

Comment: I would say you're on the right lines but I think Steve should _live_ on the server and not on the client